# Fluid Width Google Map

Tags: html, css

[On my page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants/fine-dining/masons-restaurant-and-bar-458.html) I've got a map url, but can't specify a fluid width 'size' which is required:

```
      <div class="small-map"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<%=server.URLEncode(""&rsAdvert("ContactPostcode"))%>&zoom=14&size=100x100&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|<%=server.URLEncode(""&rsAdvert("ContactPostcode"))%>&sensor=false"></div>
```

If someone could help me fit the parent container by giving it a fluid width and fixed height of 130px, that would be great. Also if anyone knows how to remove the black 'Map Data' part (or even a change the colour in css).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XpMDE/)

Delete the `<img/>` tag from `<div class="small-map"><img.../></div>`

Add this to your css:

```
.small-map{
background: url(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=CM13+2AA&zoom=14&size=250x250&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|CM13+2AA&sensor=false) center no-repeat;
height: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the 'size' in the url? We need to take that out and make it fluid width..

Comment: Don't worry about the sizes in the url. It just needs to be bigger than the container.
If you need it dynamic you can use inline css <div class="small-map" style="bacground:url(DYNAMIC_URL)">

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try it now, the only thing is the size blurs the quality of the map image when added to the url, and the css width is set to 100%. I'll try it and hopefully it'll work..

Comment: Thank you, that's cured the blurring, but it's now not recognising the padding on the container.. Could you help diagnose?